# How to pass context consumer to Component (Event.js) rendered by React Router only?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-context

My application is using React Router(Router.js), I'm trying to implement CentralStore using Context API to pass state to Event.js component rendered by Router.

How to pass context consumer to Component (Event.js) rendered by React Router only? Right now AppContext is undefined in Event.js.

Live code: https://codesandbox.io/s/0x83zz0jmw

```javascript
const AppContext = React.createContext();

class CentralStore extends React.Component {
  state={
    events: false,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    firebase
      .collection("events")
      .get()      
      .then( querySnapshot => {
        const events = [];
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
          events.push(doc.data());
        });
        this.setState({
          events: events
        });
      });
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <AppContext.Provider value={{
        state: this.state
      }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </AppContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}


import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import App from '../App';
import EventCreator from './EventCreator';
import NotFound from './NotFound';
import Event from './Event';
import Events from './Events';
import CentralStore from '../CentralStore';

const Router = () => (
  <CentralStore>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={App}/>
      <Route path="/create-event" component={EventCreator} />
      <Route path="/events/:eventId" component={Event} />
      <Route path="/events" component={Events} />
      <Route component={NotFound}/>
    </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </CentralStore> 
);

export default Router;

//

const Event = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  return (
      <div className="event">
         <AppContext.Consumer>
          {(context) => (
            console.log(context)
          )}
        </AppContext.Consumer> */}
      </div>
  );
}

export default Event;
```

Comment: did you import `AppContext` ?

Comment: I've tried to import it in Event.js as import import AppContext from '../CentralStore' - not working. I'm not exporting AppContext anywhere. I have no idea how to import it.

Comment: I exported AppContext in CentralStore Component, now I have access to state in Event.js file is that good method handling ContextAPI with React Router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by exporting AppContext from CentralStore component

```
// The missing export

export const AppContext = React.createContext();

class CentralStore extends React.Component {
  state={
    events: false,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    firebase
      .collection("events")
      .get()      
      .then( querySnapshot => {
        const events = [];
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
          events.push(doc.data());
        });
        this.setState({
          events: events
        });
      });
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <AppContext.Provider value={{
        state: this.state
      }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </AppContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}
```